# How to iterate/loop over a folder of images in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to loop over a folder of images in OpenCv. Each images is a line of text. I would like to segment each line into words and then save each word as an image. I have used the following code which works well on a single image at a time. But when I try to apply it on all the files in the folder, it just exports one of them and doesn't start looping over them all.
I'll appreciate your help and thank you in advance.
ayaasiin

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import glob
corpus_dir = Path('data')
files = list(corpus_dir.glob(pattern='*.jpg'))
files
for f in files:
    image = Image.open(f)
    image = cv2.imread(str(f))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU |
                                          cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.imwrite('threshold_image.jpg',thresh1)
    rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,30))
    dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 6)
    cv2.imwrite('dilation_image.jpg',dilation)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    im2 = img.copy()
crop_number=1 
cnt = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[1:])
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if h > 50 and w > 50:
        roi = im2[y:y+h, 0:x]
    #Draw the bounding box on the text area
        rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
​
​
    # Crop the bounding box area
    cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    
    cv2.imwrite("sawir "+str(crop_number)+".jpeg",cropped)
    crop_number+=1
```

Comment: You are overwriting `contours` in the files loop on each iteration, so when the second loop is reached, only the last contour is stored in `contours`

Comment: "help me debug my program" is off-topic. please review [help/on-topic] and [ask]. and find something that teaches you how to debug python programs.

Comment: Hi, would you please tell me how to stop the overwriting you mentioned. Thanks.- Yasin